# subtracting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server where I have the scores for some competencies, I have one score for the standard and one for the actual score. For instance S25 is the actual score and C25 is the standard for the score. I need to find the difference between the two so I can see who was above and below the standard and cannot figure out how to get the subtract to work. THe way I tried was

```
Select (S25) - (C25) AS 25_Score
```

Which did not work

Comment: Did you get an error?  Why does it not work is the data wrong?

Comment: Are "S25" and "C25" your column names?

Comment: Apologies, the error is Unable to Parse Query Text

Comment: "did not work" is meaningless without information about what "did not work" means. You also need to tell us what `S25` and `C25` are - are they columns in your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If table starts with a number, bracket it, and that might work.  What error do you get?

```
select (S25)-(C25) AS [25_Score]
from table_name
```

Comment: Cannot believe I forgot about that rule.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should work if your columns are a numeric datatype.

The only issue I see is you are starting the alias with a number. You will need to escape the number value with a square bracket:

```
Select (S25) - (C25) AS [25_Score]
from yt;
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a12ab/2)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the column is of **varchar** so you have to `convert`

```
select convert(int,[S25])-convert(int,[C25]) AS [25_Score]
from table_name
```